# How do you sort (alphabetically by keys) a $_POST request in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I'm looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php as a reference. I'm trying to sort the $_POST by the keys. This is what I am trying, but it only prints "1". What else needs to happen, or what is missing? Thank.

```
<?php
    $data = krsort($_POST);
    print_r( $data );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `ksort()`  is true or value, whether or not the sorting was successful, instead of the sorted array.

Try:

```
<?php
    krsort($_POST);
    print_r( $_POST );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`krsort` returns a boolean - TRUE on success, FALSE on failure. Try `print_r($_POST);` and see what comes out - the array should be sorted!

Answer (score 2):

The array sorting functions typically modify the array in-place - so you'd want to `print_r($_POST)` instead. The reason you're getting `1` right now as your output is because the return value from the sort functions is a status code indicating whether or not the array was able to be sorted properly - `1` indicates success.

Answer (score 0):

Technically none of these are correct. ksort() and krsort() sort by key, yes, but it's not alphabetical -- it's low to high and high to low.

This: array("iPhone","Android","Symbian")

Would order the elements Android, Symbian then iPhone due to the fact that low to high does not ignore case.

To sort an array alphabetically by keys you'd have to do a user defined uksort()